# Watch console for errors

Tags: console, cypress

I have an app using canvas elements, which are difficult to test with javascript but it does throw messages to the console.

How can I watch for errors written to the console?

I tried monkey patching the window console, but it's not working.

```js
const messages = []

window.console.error = (msg) => {
  messages.push(msg)
})

// actions causing error

expect(messages.length).to.eq(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch console messages with Cypress `cy.spy()`, ref [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spy.html#Method)

```js
let spy;
Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  spy = cy.spy(win.console, "error")  
})

// actions causing error

cy.then(() => {  
  expect(spy).not.to.be.called
})
```