# How could I achieve counting all errors during the given portion of tests and listing them at the very end in Cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to achieve the script collecting all errors and returning them all at once after this portion of tests finishes.

My premise is to count win.console.error and accessing the description of the error object, is my premise correct? How could I achiveve it please?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the errors. See [Watch console for errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72766947/16997707) for a spy on `console.error`

Comment: I am working with win.console - error, warning, debug and log. I use on('uncaught:exception') returning false to be able to not interrupt program run. And I am interested in getting to know which practise is relevant towards by goal. In this matter it would be interesting to know, how to collect the text or the generated error from the object I am saving into array.

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track. I've found that if app throws an error, you need `on('uncaught:exception')` but if it only calls `console.error('something went wrong')` then you need to spy on the console.error method.